# Adview Error Parsing XML Unbound Prefix Android

Tags: android, layout, xml-parsing, admob

I'm having a hell of a time getting AdMob working. I've had error after error and scrapped the whole thing more than once. Now I'm getting an error from the XML saying it won't parse right. Here's the code as it stands. I've looked at other answers but I can not seem to figure out what's wrong. If anyone could take a look at my layout file and let me know what I'm doing wrong I'd *greatly* appreciate it. For what it's worth I'm using the code straight from the AdMob site adapted to my own application.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/AdLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Ad Placeholder -->

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a15138b1a7adad2"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/BaseScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/baseVerticalLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Sad" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Happy" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/happinessBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Tired" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Awake" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/energyBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Calm" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Anxious" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/anxietyBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/No_Pain" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Max_Pain" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/painBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteTextFieldID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Note_Hint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="@integer/NoteLimit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enterButtonID"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="dialogPop"
            android:text="@string/EnterButtonText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change:

```
android:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

To

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

AdMob requires you to use the attributes defined in their package. So that we don't have to type out that URL each time, we declare an XML namespace using `xmlns`, like we do for android. You were prefixing the declaration with `android` instead of `xmlns`, which was resulting in your error.

Comment: Is that all it was? Why did it have to be that? I ask why because it'll help me know for the future.

Comment: Raghav, include reason behind this so that he/she will come to know and I am sure he/she will not make such mistakes again.

Comment: Ohhhhhh!!! Criminy now I feel stupid but it makes sense now. Thank you so much for both the solution (and more importantly) the reasoning behind it. Yeah, I won't do that again any time soon. =)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line your layout

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```